# How to find the last and second last word in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list :

```
fruits = ['apple', 'oranges', 'pineapples', 'mangoes', 'avocado', 'berries']
```

How do I extract the last and second last item on the list using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = [fruits[-1], fruits[-2]]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python offers a lot of ways to manage lists with custom indices, conditions...

```py
fruits = ['apple', 'oranges', 'pineapples', 'mangoes', 'avocado', 'berries']

result = [fruits[-2], fruits[-1]] #Last and second last items
result2 = fruits[-2:-1] #All items between second last and the last items
result3 = fruits[-2:] #All items from the second last
```

All those variables will contain the same elements. In my point of view you should use the third one:

```py
result = fruits[-2:]
```